Is there a helper method to confirm PSBTs?
Does anyone know of a library/method in Java that I can pass a String into and see if it is a properly formatted PSBT in base64?

the bitcoin-s library

May be this ExtLibJ parse method

I can find some PSBT related pull requests in ACINQ’s Kotlin library, which I think compiles to JRE. BitcoinJ does not have support for PSBTs, judging from this open pull request. I’m not aware of another Java-based library that has PSBT support.
